# SQUASHFS ERROR after installing ubuntu on Hyper-V

Tags: squashfs

I am trying to install Ubuntu on Hyper-V, After installation while restarting the machine I am getting SQUASHFS error, looks like file system related, but I am not sure how to resolve it.

I have tried with different version of Ubuntu but I have got this error every single time. If anyone knows the root cause of this issue, kindly help me out.

Please see the attached screenshot for details.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [Formatting Help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).